# Inheritance and polymorphism in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I have 2 classes: `Triangle` and `RightAngledTr`. `RightAngledTr` inherits from `Triangle`. The code is as follows:

The `Triangle` class:

```
class Triangle {
    public void draw() { 
        System.out.println(“Base::draw\n“);
    }

    public void computeCentroid(Triangle t) {
        System.out.println Base::centroid\n“);
    }
}
```

The `RightAngledTr` class:

```
class RightAngledTr extends Triangle {
    public void draw() { 
        System.out.println(“RightAngle::draw\n“);
    }

    public void computeCentroid(RightAngled t) {
        System.out.println(RtAngle::centroid\n“);
    }
}
```

In my Driver program I have the following lines of code:

```
Triangle tr= new RightAngledTr ();
RightAngledTr rtr= new RightAngledTr ();
tr.computeCentroid(rtr);
tr.draw();
rtr.computeCentroid(tr);
```

The output I expected was:

```
Base::centroid
Base::draw
Base::centroid
```

However, the output I got was:

```
Base::centroid
RightAngle::draw
Base::centroid
```

My question is, why does `tr.computeCentroid(rtr)` call the `Triangle` class' method when `tr.draw()` calls the `RightAngleTr` class' method?

It doesn't make sense. Liskov substitution principle doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: "Overloaded methods use early binding whereas overridden methods use late binding". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915828/how-overloading-is-compile-time-and-overriding-is-runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how java works.  *The draw () method is overridden*.

Have a look at oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) article for understanding the concepts.

> An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.

`Triangle` (parent) holds the reference of `RightAngledTr` (child) and `draw()` method is invoked on child objects. It's called overriding feature.

*Childs are type of parents*.  Parent holding child instance invokes child's overridden method.  If method is not present in child, parent method will be invoked.

*Overriding* is redefining base class (parent) behaviour with same signature. If you change the signature of base class method in child class, it's called overloading. You have done the same for other method : `computeCentroid()`.

But do not expect the same for same variables declared in both parent and child.

***Variables are not overridden. Only methods are overridden***.

Answer (score 3):

The signatures of the computeCentroid() method are different. You are therefore not overriding, but overloading.

Comment: He is talking about `draw()` method i think

Comment: And this is why you always use `@Override`.

Comment: But `tr` is an object of type `Triangle`, so why is the `draw()` method of the `Triangle` class not called when I do `tr.draw()` ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the method draw on the specialised object. Even when you wrap it inside the base class you are calling the overridden draw method.