# Examples of dynamic polymorphism in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, oop

I would like to know if there are any other examples of dynamic polymorphism except method overriding in C#. I understand method overriding is a form of dynamic polymorphism, but is this the *only* example of that?

Comment: `dynamic` keyword for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Overloading is Compile Time and Overriding is Runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915828/how-overloading-is-compile-time-and-overriding-is-runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below example of polymorphism. We have a class 'SalaryCalculator', which has a method 'Calculate' with parameter 'IEmployee'. 'Calculate' method don't who what is 'IEmployee'. It can be any class implements 'IEmployee', which is the polymorphism.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Salarycalculator salaryCalculator = new Salarycalculator();
        salaryCalculator.calculate(new Architect());
    }


}

public class Salarycalculator
{
    public void calculate(IEmployee employee)
    {
        employee.CalculateSalary();
    }
}

public interface IEmployee
{
    void CalculateSalary();
}



public class Developer : IEmployee
{
    public void CalculateSalary()
    {

    }
}

public class Architect : IEmployee
{
    public void CalculateSalary()
    {

    }
}

}
```

Runtime polymorphism works not with object initialization but the place receiving the object. In this example, 'calculate(IEmployee employee)' where 'Calculate' method comes to know the type of 'IEmployee' during runtime only. It can be of type 'Developer' or 'Architect', which means 'Calculate' method will execute polymorphically based on object type.

Comment: Hi, sorry i am new to this. How is it dynamically getting assigned when we are specifying object type to be Architect() type?

Comment: Runtime polymorphism works not with object initialization but the place receiving the object. In the example, I have given, 'calculate(IEmployee employee)' where 'Calculate' method comes to know the type of 'IEmployee' during runtime only. I have edited answer to explain a bit more.